# "hugest" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I saw an article on yahoo yesterday and thought I'd ask, is "hugest" a real word? I assume whoever wrote the article understands what they are trying to say, but it just seems wrong and foreign to my brain. I would have figured "largest" is much more appealing of an adjective.

http://www.wired.com/2016/04/worlds-hugest-jet-engine-wider-737s-fuselage/

So basically, is using huge with the suffix "est" correct in all manners, except for the fact it sounds strange?

Comment: It does sound strange, I'll grant you that. There aren't really any other one-syllable adjectives or adverbs that rhyme with *huge* that we can compare it with, either.

Comment: I'd never use it in a sentence, and it strikes me as odd that someone writing an article for a large publication would when "largest" is much easier. But, I guess, attention grabbing, isn't it?

Comment: Did you understand what it means?  If so, it is a "real word".

Comment: I do understand what it means, (thanks to Lawrence in the answer) what I was trying to ask was if it was acceptable to add "est" to the word, if it was an absolute adjective.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.  (In other words, did you look in a dictionary??)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, *huge* sounds like an [absolute adjective](http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/what-are-absolute-adjectives), but the following dictionary entry explicitly allows both comparative and superlative forms for *huge*:

> **Huge** *adjective (huger, hugest)*
>   1 Extremely large; enormous
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/huge)

This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=huge%2Chugest%2Clarge%2Clargest&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chuge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chugest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clarge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clargest%3B%2Cc0) comparing *huge/hugest* with *large/largest* appears to show that the relative usage of the respective superlative forms are roughly proportional. But in reality, as Peter Shor notes with a much clearer [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hugest%2Fhuge%2C%20largest%2Flarge&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28hugest%20/%20huge%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28largest%20/%20large%29%3B%2Cc0), the usage of *hugest* vs *huge* is tiny compared with the usage of *largest* vs *large*.

This confirms the subjective assessment that *hugest* isn't used much. Here's an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hugest%2Cpyknic%2Cventripotent&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chugest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpyknic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cventripotent%3B%2Cc0) comparing *hugest* with an antonym of sorts, [*pyknic*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pyknic) (short and fat), and [*ventripotent*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ventripotent) (big-bellied) showing that there are indeed real words that are currently less used than *hugest*.

Comment: "The Ngram comparing huge/hugest with large/largest shows ..." No it doesn't. [Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hugest%2Fhuge%2C+largest%2Flarge&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28hugest%20/%20huge%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28largest%20/%20large%29%3B%2Cc0) is the right Ngram to look at. "largest/large" is more than 10%. "hugest/huge" has never been more than around half a percent, and is much less nowadays. But I agree in that I would definitely say *hugest* is grammatical ... it's used more than many things that are clearly words.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks - that's a very useful way of expressing the statistics! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you. I'm glad you threw in the absolute adjective, that what I was asking but couldn't find the right way to ask!

Comment: @Rayray You're welcome. Glad you liked it :) .

Answer (score 0):

yep it's a real word. Check out those examples:
http://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=hugest